# Get lat and lng from google using Unity WWW class

Tags: c#, json, google-maps, unity-game-engine

I am trying to use the geo service from google inside my Unity. Here is how I do this:

```
WWW www = new WWW("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=1600+Amphitheatre+Parkway,+Mountain+View,+CA&oe=utf-8&key="+googleKey);
yield return www;

if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(www.error)){
    print(www.error);
} else {
    var newobject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(www.text);
    print ("Object: " + newobject);
}
```

This part works fine and I get the result I want... But know I need to only get the latitude and longitude out of the result, but am not sure how to do this?

Here is the result I get from google:

```
{
  "results": [
    {
      "address_components": [
        {
          "long_name": "1600",
          "short_name": "1600",
          "types": [
            "street_number"
          ]
        },
        {
          "long_name": "Amphitheatre Parkway",
          "short_name": "Amphitheatre Pkwy",
          "types": [
            "route"
          ]
        },
        {
          "long_name": "Mountain View",
          "short_name": "Mountain View",
          "types": [
            "locality",
            "political"
          ]
        },
        {
          "long_name": "Santa Clara County",
          "short_name": "Santa Clara County",
          "types": [
            "administrative_area_level_2",
            "political"
          ]
        },
        {
          "long_name": "California",
          "short_name": "CA",
          "types": [
            "administrative_area_level_1",
            "political"
          ]
        },
        {
          "long_name": "United States",
          "short_name": "US",
          "types": [
            "country",
            "political"
          ]
        },
        {
          "long_name": "94043",
          "short_name": "94043",
          "types": [
            "postal_code"
          ]
        }
      ],
      "formatted_address": "1600 Amphitheatre Pkwy, Mountain View, CA 94043, USA",
      "geometry": {
        "location": {
          "lat": 37.422364,
          "lng": -122.084364
        },
        "location_type": "ROOFTOP",
        "viewport": {
          "northeast": {
            "lat": 37.4237129802915,
            "lng": -122.0830150197085
          },
          "southwest": {
            "lat": 37.421015019708513,
            "lng": -122.0857129802915
          }
        }
      },
      "place_id": "ChIJ2eUgeAK6j4ARbn5u_wAGqWA",
      "types": [
        "street_address"
      ]
    }
  ],
  "status": "OK"
}
```

I guess I need to go to this:

```
"geometry": {
        "location": {
          "lat": 37.422364,
          "lng": -122.084364
        },
```

But how do I do this?

Any help is appreciated and thanks in advance :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I guess I need to go to this:
>
> ```
> "geometry": {
>     "location": {
>       "lat": 37.422364,
>       "lng": -122.084364
>     },
> ```

You're right. You need the `geometry` object within the Json. I've used Google's API to get objects back before.

You need to create some classes in C# that map to the same/relevant properties from the Json object. Then you can use JsonConvert in order to convert your Json string back to some C# objects -http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/t_newtonsoft_json_jsonconvert.htm

A great tool to use is http://json2csharp.com/ which allows you to paste your Json code in, and get some recognisable C# classes out the other end.

Obviously, you could remove any properties you definitely don't need.

Your end result should look something like this (copy/pasted to/from json2csharp.com):

```
public class AddressComponent
{
    public string long_name { get; set; }
    public string short_name { get; set; }
    public List<string> types { get; set; }
}

public class Location
{
    public double lat { get; set; }
    public double lng { get; set; }
}

public class Northeast
{
    public double lat { get; set; }
    public double lng { get; set; }
}

public class Southwest
{
    public double lat { get; set; }
    public double lng { get; set; }
}

public class Viewport
{
    public Northeast northeast { get; set; }
    public Southwest southwest { get; set; }
}

public class Geometry
{
    public Location location { get; set; }
    public string location_type { get; set; }
    public Viewport viewport { get; set; }
}

public class Result
{
    public List<AddressComponent> address_components { get; set; }
    public string formatted_address { get; set; }
    public Geometry geometry { get; set; }
    public string place_id { get; set; }
    public List<string> types { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public List<Result> results { get; set; }
    public string status { get; set; }
}
```

To then use JsonConvert to create some objects, you can do:

```
RootObject rootObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(www.text);
```

You can then access your `Geometry` objects in the `Result`s by iterating over them (or accessing the `.First()`) etc.

Like this:

```
foreach (var resultObject in rootObject.results)
{
    var geometry = resultObject.geometry;
    var location = geometry.location;
    var lat = location.lat;
    var lng = location.lng
}
```

To tidy things up, you can also rename some properties to make them more "friendly", and then decorate them with an attribute, so that JsonConvert still knows which Json property to map.

Like this:

```
[JsonProperty(PropertyName = "a_json_property")]
public string ACSharpProperty { get; set; }
```

Any questions, let me know.

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: Hi Geoff, for some reason I can not make this work :-/ I am not sure what to do with the geometryObject and how to get the lat and lng from this. The other example I have made work though.

Comment: Whoops! My bad entirely - I'd got `Geometry` stuck in my head as the end-game. You need to deserialize to a `Result` object first, then access the properties from `resultObject.Geometry` and so on and so-forth. I've updated my answer for you :)

Comment: Oh yes, but now I get error on this line: var location = geometry.location;

Comment: I see. Just typed out the code (I was doing it blind before) to check - I realised that you will need to create a `RootObject` from your Json first, and then iterate through the items in `rootObject.results` to get the results. Updated my answer to reflect this - it is now tried and tested working code :)

Comment: Perfect... Thanks :-) You just saved my day (y)

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a data structure to store the Json data. With Unity's `JsonUtility.FromJson`, you can then extract the json data and store it to that data structure.

Remember that since results is an `array`/`list`, you have to loop through it to get all values. You must remove `{ get; set; }` from each of classes and must also include `[System.Serializable]` to the top of each one. No external API is required to do this as long as you have Unity 5.3 and above. Here is a tested complete solution.

```
[System.Serializable]
public class AddressComponent
{
    public string long_name;
    public string short_name;
    public List<string> types;
}
[System.Serializable]
public class Location
{
    public double lat;
    public double lng;
}
[System.Serializable]
public class Northeast
{
    public double lat;
    public double lng;
}
[System.Serializable]
public class Southwest
{
    public double lat;
    public double lng;
}
[System.Serializable]
public class Viewport
{
    public Northeast northeast;
    public Southwest southwest;
}
[System.Serializable]
public class Geometry
{
    public Location location;
    public string location_type;
    public Viewport viewport;
}
[System.Serializable]
public class Result
{
    public List<AddressComponent> address_components;
    public string formatted_address;
    public Geometry geometry;
    public string place_id;
    public List<string> types;
}
[System.Serializable]
public class GoogleJson
{
    public List<Result> results;
    public string status;
}
```

And to use it:

```
void Start()
{
    //Replace value with what you got from WWW
    string value = "{\r\n  \"results\": [\r\n    {\r\n      \"address_components\": [\r\n        {\r\n          \"long_name\": \"1600\",\r\n          \"short_name\": \"1600\",\r\n          \"types\": [\r\n            \"street_number\"\r\n          ]\r\n        },\r\n        {\r\n          \"long_name\": \"Amphitheatre Parkway\",\r\n          \"short_name\": \"Amphitheatre Pkwy\",\r\n          \"types\": [\r\n            \"route\"\r\n          ]\r\n        },\r\n        {\r\n          \"long_name\": \"Mountain View\",\r\n          \"short_name\": \"Mountain View\",\r\n          \"types\": [\r\n            \"locality\",\r\n            \"political\"\r\n          ]\r\n        },\r\n        {\r\n          \"long_name\": \"Santa Clara County\",\r\n          \"short_name\": \"Santa Clara County\",\r\n          \"types\": [\r\n            \"administrative_area_level_2\",\r\n            \"political\"\r\n          ]\r\n        },\r\n        {\r\n          \"long_name\": \"California\",\r\n          \"short_name\": \"CA\",\r\n          \"types\": [\r\n            \"administrative_area_level_1\",\r\n            \"political\"\r\n          ]\r\n        },\r\n        {\r\n          \"long_name\": \"United States\",\r\n          \"short_name\": \"US\",\r\n          \"types\": [\r\n            \"country\",\r\n            \"political\"\r\n          ]\r\n        },\r\n        {\r\n          \"long_name\": \"94043\",\r\n          \"short_name\": \"94043\",\r\n          \"types\": [\r\n            \"postal_code\"\r\n          ]\r\n        }\r\n      ],\r\n      \"formatted_address\": \"1600 Amphitheatre Pkwy, Mountain View, CA 94043, USA\",\r\n      \"geometry\": {\r\n        \"location\": {\r\n          \"lat\": 37.422364,\r\n          \"lng\": -122.084364\r\n        },\r\n        \"location_type\": \"ROOFTOP\",\r\n        \"viewport\": {\r\n          \"northeast\": {\r\n            \"lat\": 37.4237129802915,\r\n            \"lng\": -122.0830150197085\r\n          },\r\n          \"southwest\": {\r\n            \"lat\": 37.421015019708513,\r\n            \"lng\": -122.0857129802915\r\n          }\r\n        }\r\n      },\r\n      \"place_id\": \"ChIJ2eUgeAK6j4ARbn5u_wAGqWA\",\r\n      \"types\": [\r\n        \"street_address\"\r\n      ]\r\n    }\r\n  ],\r\n  \"status\": \"OK\"\r\n}";
    GoogleJson gJson = null;
    gJson = JsonUtility.FromJson<GoogleJson>(value);

    for (int i = 0; i < gJson.results.Count; i++)
    {
        Debug.Log("RESULT: " + i);
        Debug.Log("Geometry lat: " + gJson.results[i].geometry.location.lat);
        Debug.Log("Geometry lng: " + gJson.results[i].geometry.location.lng);
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice! Is that creating a `dynamic` object?

Comment: @GeoffJames Yes, it is. It creates it then assigns the result to it. If you don't want it to create new instance of that Object, you can use `JsonUtility.FromJsonOverwrite` but that means that you must do `GoogleJson gJson = new GoogleJson ();` before calling that function.   It looks like we both use the-same link in your answer to do our json  work.

Comment: I thought I recognised it. When I started out doing some Google Geocode stuff for a project, I was using a `dynamic` object to parse out some Json. It got really fiddly and ugly in the end, so I opted for a good old C# class. http://json2csharp.com is a life-saving tool!

Comment: I agree. json2csharp.com is a life-saving tool.  `JsonUtility.FromJson` is still new to Unity and is being improved. Happy coding!